# OpenFire - Google Talk Federation

Tags: openfire, google-talk

I have a OpenFire 3.7.1 Server configured on im.domain.com. I want to Google Talk Federation on this server, so that my users can chat with other GTalk users.

This is my SRV Records on GoDaddy.

[image: My SRV Records on GoDaddy.]

I am very new to OpenFire & Jabber. I've a OpenFire which is configured on im.domain.com which runs on AWS EC2 Micro Instance.

But when I test this using http://kingant.net/check_xmpp_dns/?h=jabber.org it fails.

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved problem. The problem was with the DNS Records. I have changed the "Name" to "im" and renamed service to "_xmpp-client" from "_jabber".

Comment: This is not a discussion thread.  Edit your question to add more information.  This is not an answer.

Comment: @Robin That is my answer to the question. I've updated it. Hope that it's clear now. I know this is not a discussion thread... :)